# problem in Custom Button Action in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI,

In my application I am displaying a list in scrollView. I have placed custom btn against each item
    in scrollView. In btn action I have to change unselected image to Selected Image. But when I click first btn, last btn image is changed.

Code:

```
    - (void)reLoadView 
      {

    float yCoordinateStartLocation = 20;
    float xCoordinateStartLocatioForItem = 80;
    float xCoordinateStartLocatioForButton=30;
    float questionWidth =100;
    UIFont* questionFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:54.0/255.0 blue: 129.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *bgcolor = [UIColor clearColor];

    for(int i=0; i<[itemArray count]; i++)
    {
    showItems *showItem = [itemArray objectAtIndex:i];

     float itemHeight = [ShowViewController calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:showItem.itemName    :questionFont : questionWidth :UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];


    itemLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    itemLabel.frame=CGRectMake(xCoordinateStartLocatioForItem,yCoordinateStartLocation,questionWidth,40);
    itemLabel.text =showItem.itemName;
    itemLabel.textColor = color;
    itemLabel.font = questionFont;
    itemLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    itemLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
    itemLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    itemLabel.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
    [scrollView addSubview:itemLabel];


    UIImage *unSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unChecked.png"];
    checkBoxBttn = [[MyCustomButton alloc] initWithIdValue:showItem.itemName tagValue:tagCount];
    //checkBoxBttn = [[MyCustomButton alloc] initWithIdValue:showItem.itemName];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xCoordinateStartLocatioForButton,yCoordinateStartLocation, 30, 30);
    [checkBoxBttn setFrame:frame];
    checkBoxBttn.tag=tagCount;


    [checkBoxBttn setBackgroundImage:unSelectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBoxBttn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [checkBoxBttn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scrollView addSubview:checkBoxBttn];
    tagCount++;


    yCoordinateStartLocation = yCoordinateStartLocation + itemHeight + 20;

    }

      scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, yCoordinateStartLocation+50);
      }



       -(void)checkButtonAction:(MyCustomButton*)sender
{
    NSString *sndStr = [sender itemName];
    //taglabel=[sender tagNumber];
    //NSString *tagNo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",taglabel];



    for(int i=0; i<[itemArray count]; i++)
    {
    showItems *showItem = [itemArray objectAtIndex:i];


    if([sndStr isEqualToString:showItem.itemName])
    {
            printf("\n ====     checkBoxBttn.tag:%d",   checkBoxBttn.tag);
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    [checkBoxBttn setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    }

   }
```

Can anyOne help me in this.
       Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Where you define checkBoxBttn in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Well couldn't figure out what you were trying to achieve here. At some point, I felt a UITableView might've suited your needs.

The reason why the last button is changing when you tap the first button is that `checkBoxBttn` was set to the last button at the end of the loop in `-reLoadView` so when you reference it again in `-checkButtonAction:` it refers to the last button and not the button that received the user action.

Assuming that you want to change the image of the button that receives the user action, you might want to use the following code –

```
-(void)checkButtonAction:(MyCustomButton*)sender
{
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Of course, this is not for flipping. Flipping will involve additional work.

Answer (score 0):

this line  make a problem
 [checkBoxBttn setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

u have to update checkBoxBttn background image through tag wise